# How do I bring a child layout in View/Focus/Screen

Tags: android

I have the following Layout structure

```
    <LinearLayout
        id="@+id/papaLayout"
        >
        <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
        <Relativelayout
            id="@+id/daughter_A"
            >
        //Some Welcome Message here. And Only One Clickable Item here.
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
        <Relativelayout
            id="@+id/daughter_B"
            >
        //Some Clickable Items here
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

When my app loads daughter_A takes all of screen. Inside the daughter_A layout there is one button. I want the daughter_B to occupy screen as i click the button in daughter_A.

I don't want to use ScrollView. Can this be Done without using ScrollView ?

Comment: `View.BringToFront()`

Comment: @Alice RelativeLayout **RLb1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.daughter_B);**
   _RLb1.bringToFront();_ didn't work

Comment: Why dont you go with Fragments?

Comment: @Alice Can you give a small example of what you are suggesting(if possible).

Comment: make the visibiliy of daughterA gone on button click

Comment: @billgates That did it ! and lol !